# How to Git the latest tag of a submodule & excluding tags that contain certain words on it

Tags: git, gitlab, tags, git-submodules

I have cloned recursively a repo from GitLab and then got the tags of the submodules by using the following command:

```
git submodule foreach git tag -l
```

So as an example. I have the following two submodules (components), **AccltrInterLckDet** and **AccltrInterLckSwt**, listed along with all of its tags:

```
Entering 'components/AccltrInterLckDet'
01.01.20210702.001
01.02.202203.001
beagledaimler.02.202211.001
legendgold.02.202210.001
octanegold.02.202210.001
titanium.02.202210.001
titanium.02.202211.001
Entering 'components/AccltrInterLckSwt'
01.01.20210706.001
01.01.20210727.002
01.02.202203.001
beagledaimler.02.202211.001
legendgold.02.202210.001
legendgold.02.202210.002
legendsilver.02.202211.001
octaneblue.02.202211.001
octanegold.02.202210.001
octanegold.02.202210.002
octanegold.02.202210.003
titanium.02.202210.001
titanium.02.202211.001
```

Here's my question, How can I:

1. **Exclude** all tags that contain the words "titanium" "legend" "beagle"
2. Get only the **newest** tag

Not sure if there's a way to add these two conditions in the original command.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which tag is the newest? Does gold precede silver, or does gold come after silver? Are beagles older than titanium? (Well, I guess their relative ages don't matter since you intend to exclude both titanium and beagle.)

Comment: In any case, you're likely to have to write your own script. `git tag` can be told to use glob pattern matching, but that's not sufficiently powerful here. Write a small program (in shell, or awk, or whatever) that reads input lines, rejects invalid ones, and uses whatever technique you use to determine "newness". Pick the newest non-rejected tag and print it when you reach the end of the input.

Comment: the latest version from newest to oldest is: `titanium.02.202211.001`, `beagledaimler.02.202211.001`, `titanium.02.202210.001`, `legendgold.02.202210.001`,
`octanegold.02.202210.001`,
`01.02.202203.001`, 
`01.01.20210702.001`

Comment: If we decide to do away with rejecting the words and do a simpler program like  ordering it from the latest tag to the oldest that that was added. Can you please point me in how to do this?

Comment: You're still going to have to write some code of your own. Git does have a "version sort" option (similar to GNU `sort -V`) but it won't handle your requirements.